# Android how to clip view with XML Circle shape?

Tags: java, android, animation, view, clip

I need to draw an empty circle and I know I can have one like this :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:thicknessRatio="2"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</shape>
```

and then I just have to set it to any view's background and there it shows on the screen.

However, the view containing the circle as background is a square (or a rectangle) with **a defined height and width**. Therefore, the circle is drawn inside the view.

But what if I want to **clip that said view** ?

Let's my view-circle is inside a Layout (Linear or Relative) and fills up the parent (`match_parent`). Let's say this layout is red. What I want to do, is use the circle to clip the red layout so that only the red is shown inside the circle : the red **must not leave the circle bounds**.

Somehow, I can manage, with `android:clipChildren="true"` so that nothing goes further than the view squared borders. But that is not **enough** because the animated content do leave the circle and are halted at the view borders.

Is there any way to accomplish this ? I would like to remain on the XML level here. No canvas, not code to run at runtime. Is it possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: no, you cannot do that at xml level, only direct `Canvas` can do that

Comment: ok thanks. And how can I do that ? :) Is it expensive in terms of CPU load ?

Comment: expensive?  is xml not expensive?  after all everything you write in xml has to be executed somehow in low level Canvas stuff

Comment: I see. Thank you for your insight. So I should create my own View class, and override onDraw() to use a Canvas so that I can clip the content of the layout ? What if the the content is animated ? Like the color changing, opacity etc... will the Canvas keep on clipping outside the circle ? It's really important for me. Thanks !

Comment: if you want to clip the paren layout you should create a class that extends that layout and override its `draw` / `dispatchDraw` method

Comment: Can you provide a guide to accomplish this? It's same like a hassle to create a custom view class with attributes sets. And I still don't know how to use canvas to draw the circle ^^ thanks!

Comment: `"""And I still don't know how to use canvas to draw the circle"""` sorry you have to learn that by yourself